# VBA Read Data from a Closed Excel File or Workbook without Opening it

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that completes my data, but I would like it to work in the background so that only input appears and then it copies the data to me. I added this to my code  `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`it shows that it works remotely " in the background", the input box appears but then nothing happens, no error, but the data is not copied. How to change code ?

````
Sub Makro10()

Dim vDate As Date
Dim wbMe As Workbook
Dim data_wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim inputbx As String
Dim loc As Range, lc As Long
Dim app As New Excel.Application

'Set workbook'
    
Set wbMe = ActiveWorkbook
With wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Rows("1:1")
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
  End With
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

file_name = selectFilePK
If file_name = "" Then Exit Sub

   'Set data file
   Set data_wb = app.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
   
   'paste copy like value and change to date format'
   data_wb.Sheets("Final").Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
 
 Do
        inputbx = InputBox("Enter Date, FORMAT; YYYY-MM-DD", , Format(VBA.Now, "YYYY-MM-DD"))
        If inputbx = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        On Error Resume Next
        vDate = DateValue(inputbx)
        On Error GoTo 0
        DateIsValid = IsDate(vDate)
        If Not DateIsValid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid date.", vbExclamation
    Loop Until DateIsValid
       

     

     data_wb.Worksheets("Final").Activate
     With data_wb.Worksheets("Final")
        Set loc = .Cells.Find(what:=vDate)
      If Not loc Is Nothing Then
            lc = .Cells(loc.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            .Range(.Cells(109, loc.Column), .Cells(123, lc)).Copy
      Set locPaste = wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Cells.Find(what:=vDate)
      wbMe.Sheets("input_forecast").Cells(27, locPaste.Column).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        End If
    End With
data_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
Private Function selectFilePK()
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd
.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel", "*.xlsm"

If .Show = True Then selectFilePK = .SelectedItems(1)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End With


End Function```
````

Comment: Do you try saying that our attempt does not open the file/workbook "to read data"? This code line `If file_name = "" Then Exit Sub` exit your sub. The used function may not return anything and `file_name` is "". Please, try inserting this line immediately after `file_name = selectFilePK`: `Debug.Print file_name`. What does it return in Immediate Window?

Comment: Does not open the file, but an inputbox appears for the date. However, then it does nothing (not copying and pasting). Maybe, I pasted` Application.ScreenUpdating = False `incorrectly

Comment: Please, try inserting this line immediately after `file_name = selectFilePK`: `Debug.Print file_name: Stop`. What does it return in Immediate Window when stopped on the line? If it looks OK , try inserting the next code line after `Set loc = .Cells.Find(what:=vDate)`: Debug.print loc is Nothing: Stop`, and press `F5`. What does it return on stopped on the line?

Comment: It doesn't show anything, I guess it opens the file then it goes all the way to the input box

Comment: When does it  not show anything? If at the first inserted line, this means that no path string has been returned. Second time it  must return `True` or `False`... In order to see Immediate Window, please press `Ctrl + G`, being in VBE... If you can see the InputBox, please comment the first testing line. What the second one does return? Does your code go out from the loop of Date setting?

Comment: C:\Users\V1410190\Documents\KCopy File.xlsm  its only whats immediate shows

Comment: Did you press `F5` after stopping on the line? It should stop to the second one. Anyhow, I suggested to comment/delete the first one, since the code reaches the InputBox part...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237597/discussion-between-whyexcelme-and-faneduru).